# Is sharekit open source acceptable by apple in iphone application?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

hi i am an iphone /ipad developer , i am using sharekit open source for facebook/twitter sharing , i want to know about its acceptance on itunes by apple.
Please give me any idea about it

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes I used Share kit in my applications and I never get any problem at appstore.